# need help in solving sql problems using order by to order building floor

Tags: sql-server, sql-order-by

i have this building floor data selected:

```
6
5
4
3
2
1
UG
GM
G
LG
5B
5A
B1
B2
```

for this sorting i use this kind of Order by :

```
order by 
                    (case when ISNUMERIC(floorNo) = 1 then CAST(floorNo AS Int) end) desc , 
                     (case when ISNUMERIC(left(floorNo,1)) = 0 and ISNUMERIC(substring(floorNo,2,1)) = 1 then floorNo end) asc,
                    (case when ISNUMERIC(floorNo) = 0 and left(floorNo,1) <>'L' then floorNo end) desc
```

but i want to make it like this :

```
6
5B
5A
5
4
3
2
1
UG
GM
G
LG
B1
B2
```

Can ANy one Help me solve it?

Comment: The presence of both numerical and character data in your column will make it very hard to generate this sort order in SQL Server.  The best thing to do might be to have separate columns for the numeric and text components.

Comment: In addition,Also different people use different term for floor name.for example GM may be term as GF and so on. Technically no logic will work.Also because of order of clause your query will become slow.so keep separate numeric  column.

Answer (score 0):

If you make a complicated enough (set of) case statement(s), you would eventually be able to handle all the possibilities, but it is likely to run very slow if you have a lot of data.

If I had to do this, I would probably make a separate lookup table (FloorOrder) with two columns; this floor code and an order column (integer). Create a script to populate the lookup table with all the various possibilities - pick a maximum number of floors, basements, and subfloors per floor, and make all of the possibilities with some loops. Then add all the various floors near ground floor. Make sure the order numbers are spread out enough that you can easily add other codes in between when somebody comes up with a new option (because they will).  Something like this subset.

```
Code   Order
2      2000
1C     1300
1B     1200
1A     1100
1      1000
UG     800
GM     500
G      0
LG     -300
B1     -1000
```

It doesn't really matter what the order codes are, as long as they sort the list in the right order, can be easily generated when creating the table, and leave space for fitting things in the gap. Whenever somebody comes up with a new weird floor code (some I've seen near me are things like M (Mezzanine, UM for Upper Mezzanine, etc), add new records to the FloorOrder table to fit them in. Make sure you table has an index on the floor codes

To use it, join to the FloorOrder table, sort by the Order column.